# CQL: Get access to column family that was created using old thrift client

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh, cassandra-cli

I have a ColumnFamily with one RowKey and 120 mln columns.

This is what cassandra-cli client shows:

```
[default@***] list keys;
Using default limit of 100
Using default cell limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: domain_name
=> (name=0-0-2-4.com, value=15, timestamp=1432312617718176)
=> (name=0-0-3.com, value=15, timestamp=1432312617740511)
=> (name=0-0-3.ru, value=15, timestamp=1432312617768942)
=> (name=0-0-6.com, value=15, timestamp=1432312617797960)
=> (name=0-0-7-0.net, value=9, timestamp=1337023974079142)
...
=> (name=0-0-7.com, value=15, timestamp=1432312617819952)
=> (name=0-0-7.in, value=, timestamp=1433942588507250)
=> (name=0-0-7.net, value=15, timestamp=1432312617851242)

1 Row Returned.
Elapsed time: 193 msec(s).
```

This is how it looks like in CQL:

```
cqlsh:***> describe table keys;

CREATE TABLE keys (
  key text,
  domain_name text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key))
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.100000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=1.000000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'chunk_length_kb': '64', 'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

But I can't get any data from CQL:

```
cqlsh:***> select * from keys;

(0 rows)
```

How to get access to existing data using CQL?

Comment: Can you tell us the version of C* and cqlsh. This matters as older versions of cqlsh dont use the binary protocol and that is why you might be able to describe the table. Also `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` means you should indeed have access to the data with CQL, which makes me think some kind of timeout is happening, so now my advice is supply a specific key you are after using the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @LyubenTodorov

`[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.11 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]`

Comment: @LyubenTodorov
`select * from keys where key='domain_name';` 
returns 0 results. And I have access to other tables in keyspace. I can't get results from this particular column family only. I suspect it's because of wide columns. This column famiy has 120M columns.